# "Spatial types and functions are not available" error when converting a string to DbGeometry in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, geometry

When trying to convert a string as below

```
52.0986413 5.2171528
```

to a variable of type `DbGeometry` like this

```
Geometry = System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry.FromText("POINT("+preometry+")");
```

where Geometry is of type `System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry`
I get the next errormessage:

> Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found.

Even though I have Microsoft.SqlServer.Types version 11.0.2 in my project.
Does anybody know what the problem could be?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer when I reinstalled Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.

For ASP.NET applications, add the following line of code to the Application_Start method in Global.asax.cs:

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
```

For desktop applications, add the following line of code to run before any spatial operations are performed:

```
 SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

This fixed it for me